# Favicon doesn't work. Solutions I've found don't work for my site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, favicon

Please don't kill me; I know this has been asked a lot. I've read everything I can find on how to get the favicon to show properly. Nothing I've found works. Pages and pages on Google and on here.

- IE8
- favicons from other websites work
- the tag in site.master (asp.net) is `<link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://sysmoddata1/etl/images/status/favicon.ico" />`
- have tried `CTRL+5` many times.

I can navigate to the image. It just will not work *as* the favicon.

Help?

Comment: Does it work if you just put the `favicon.ico` in the root of your website?

Comment: What is `http://sysmoddata1`? Is that on your domain or another?

Comment: I have tried that, with and without the whole URL. And yes, that's the domain. It's internal to the company.

Comment: Clear your browser cache. Reload the page. And it is ```Ctrl+F5``` not ```Ctrl+5```.

Comment: Done and done. Thanks for the correction. Still no go.